# Webcam Colored Lines - Hardware Issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

Has anyone seen this before? It's happening with any camera app (Skype, Photo Booth, Hangouts) so it doesn't appear to be software related. I'm assuming it's a hardware issue but I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this before.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: are you using the internal isight webcam or an external camera, and when you take a picture in photo booth for example does the resulting image show the same lines?

Comment: This is the internal webcam - and yes it is the same when taking a picture in photo booth.

Comment: can any one help.... coloured lines are seen on the webcamera ,but the laptop display is proper.[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/486kD.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/486kD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Note that I am GUESSING here but that looks awfully like a damaged sensor. You occasionally see similar displays on LCD panels when they go bad so this might indeed be the hardware error you think it is.

Comment: Looks like a broken camera to me indeed.